# Use fixed() for multiple patterns in stringr::str_replace_all()

Tags: r, stringr

I'd like to `str_replace()` multiple `fixed()` patterns at once, but the

```
c("pattern1" = "replacement1", "pattern2" = "replacement2", ...)
```

syntax is not working with

```
c(fixed("pattern1") = "replacement1", fixed("pattern2") = "replacement2", ...)
```

It looks like this `name = value` syntax is not possible, when I need to have a function call on the LHS.

Any ideas on how to code this with `stringr::str_replace_all()`?

`str_replace_all()` works fine when just using the regex default. I could also manage the underlying `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed()` function to work.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

sw <- dplyr::starwars %>%
  mutate(
    hair_skin_eye = str_c(hair_color, skin_color, eye_color, sep = " | ")
  ) %>%
  select(name, hair_skin_eye)

# using default (regex)
sw %>%
  mutate(
    hair_skin_eye_repl = str_replace_all(
      string = hair_skin_eye,
      c(
        "white" = "WHITE",
        "blue" = "BLUE",
        "yellow" = "YELLOW"
      )
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 87 x 3
#>    name              hair_skin_eye                 hair_skin_eye_repl           
#>    <chr>             <chr>                         <chr>                        
#>  1 Luke Skywalker    blond | fair | blue           blond | fair | BLUE          
#>  2 C-3PO             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  3 R2-D2             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  4 Darth Vader       none | white | yellow         none | WHITE | YELLOW        
#>  5 Leia Organa       brown | light | brown         brown | light | brown        
#>  6 Owen Lars         brown, grey | light | blue    brown, grey | light | BLUE   
#>  7 Beru Whitesun la~ brown | light | blue          brown | light | BLUE         
#>  8 R5-D4             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  9 Biggs Darklighter black | light | brown         black | light | brown        
#> 10 Obi-Wan Kenobi    auburn, white | fair | blue-~ auburn, WHITE | fair | BLUE-~
#> # ... with 77 more rows

# using just one pattern (fixed)
sw %>%
  mutate(
    hair_skin_eye_repl = str_replace_all(
      string = hair_skin_eye,
      pattern = fixed("white"),
      replacement = "WHITE")
  )
#> # A tibble: 87 x 3
#>    name              hair_skin_eye                 hair_skin_eye_repl           
#>    <chr>             <chr>                         <chr>                        
#>  1 Luke Skywalker    blond | fair | blue           blond | fair | blue          
#>  2 C-3PO             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  3 R2-D2             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  4 Darth Vader       none | white | yellow         none | WHITE | yellow        
#>  5 Leia Organa       brown | light | brown         brown | light | brown        
#>  6 Owen Lars         brown, grey | light | blue    brown, grey | light | blue   
#>  7 Beru Whitesun la~ brown | light | blue          brown | light | blue         
#>  8 R5-D4             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  9 Biggs Darklighter black | light | brown         black | light | brown        
#> 10 Obi-Wan Kenobi    auburn, white | fair | blue-~ auburn, WHITE | fair | blue-~
#> # ... with 77 more rows

# use underlying stringi function directly
sw %>%
  mutate(
    hair_skin_eye_repl = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(
      str = hair_skin_eye,
      pattern = c("white", "blue", "yellow"),
      replacement = c("WHITE", "BLUE", "YELLOW"),
      vectorize_all = FALSE
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 87 x 3
#>    name              hair_skin_eye                 hair_skin_eye_repl           
#>    <chr>             <chr>                         <chr>                        
#>  1 Luke Skywalker    blond | fair | blue           blond | fair | BLUE          
#>  2 C-3PO             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  3 R2-D2             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  4 Darth Vader       none | white | yellow         none | WHITE | YELLOW        
#>  5 Leia Organa       brown | light | brown         brown | light | brown        
#>  6 Owen Lars         brown, grey | light | blue    brown, grey | light | BLUE   
#>  7 Beru Whitesun la~ brown | light | blue          brown | light | BLUE         
#>  8 R5-D4             <NA>                          <NA>                         
#>  9 Biggs Darklighter black | light | brown         black | light | brown        
#> 10 Obi-Wan Kenobi    auburn, white | fair | blue-~ auburn, WHITE | fair | BLUE-~
#> # ... with 77 more rows

# using multiple patterns - doesn't work
sw %>%
mutate(
  hair_skin_eye_repl = stringr::str_replace_all(
    string = hair_skin_eye,
    c(
      fixed("white") = "WHITE",
      fixed("blue") = "BLUE",
      fixed("yellow") = "YELLOW"
    )
  )
)
#> Error: unexpected '=' in:
#> "      c(
#> fixed("white") ="
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a named vector in  `str_replace_all` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

sw %>%
  mutate(
    hair_skin_eye_repl = stringr::str_replace_all(
      string = hair_skin_eye, 
      setNames(c('WHITE', 'BLUE', 'YELLOW'), c('white', 'blue', 'yellow'))
      )
    )

#   name               hair_skin_eye                    hair_skin_eye_repl              
#   <chr>              <chr>                            <chr>                           
# 1 Luke Skywalker     blond | fair | blue              blond | fair | BLUE             
# 2 C-3PO              NA                               NA                              
# 3 R2-D2              NA                               NA                              
# 4 Darth Vader        none | white | yellow            none | WHITE | YELLOW           
# 5 Leia Organa        brown | light | brown            brown | light | brown           
# 6 Owen Lars          brown, grey | light | blue       brown, grey | light | BLUE      
# 7 Beru Whitesun lars brown | light | blue             brown | light | BLUE            
# 8 R5-D4              NA                               NA                              
# 9 Biggs Darklighter  black | light | brown            black | light | brown           
#10 Obi-Wan Kenobi     auburn, white | fair | blue-gray auburn, WHITE | fair | BLUE-gray
# … with 77 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is basically the same as what I wrote in my reprex under `# using default (regex)`. This does not take the patterns as fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole named vector in `fixed()`:

```r
sw %>%
    mutate(
        hair_skin_eye_repl = str_replace_all(
            string = hair_skin_eye,
            fixed(c(
                "white" = "WHITE",
                "blue" = "BLUE",
                "yellow" = "YELLOW"
            ))
        )
    )
```